# Stick objects to circular minimap border when offscreen in unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am doing a minimap for a 3d unity game and I want to stick the objects to the border of the minimap when they are offscreen. I've searched everywhere and I can't seem to find a good solution. This is the code I am currently using but sometimes it does not work fine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class StayInside : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform MinimapCam;
    public float MinimapSize;
    Vector3 TempV3;

    void Update()
    {
        TempV3 = transform.parent.transform.position;
        TempV3.y = transform.position.y;
        transform.position = TempV3;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(90f, MinimapCam.eulerAngles.y, 0f);
    }

    void LateUpdate()
    {
        Vector3 centerPosition = MinimapCam.transform.localPosition;

        centerPosition.y -= 0.5f;

        float Distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, centerPosition);

        if (Distance > MinimapSize)
        {
            Vector3 fromOriginToObject = transform.position - centerPosition;
            fromOriginToObject *= MinimapSize / Distance;
            transform.position = centerPosition + fromOriginToObject;
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.7f,0.7f,0.7f);
        } else
        {
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(1f, 1f, 1f);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to keep the position of the point of interest inside the MiniMap script, so You can use it and calculate the vector from mini map center (Probably player). Using this vector it is fairly easy to calculate the position on the circle edge.

```
Vector3 vectorFromPlayer = playerPos - intrestingPos;
```

And now You can easily find Your point using [this answer](https://answers.unity.com/questions/211400/find-a-position-by-knowing-the-directionvector-and.html)

```
 Vector3 miniMapEdgePos = playerPos + (vectorFromPlayer.normalised * radius);
```

Hope it helps, It's not working code, but I think You get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial Clamps the icon at the edge of the camera.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xW4zZQhRKlI

For a square mini map placed on the icon you wish to show. MinimapCam is the transform on your mini map camera. minimapSize is a float that you choose to keep the icon within a certain distance.

```
    transform.position = new Vector3(
        Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x, MinimapCam.position.x - MinimapSize, MinimapSize + MinimapCam.position.x),
        transform.position.y,
        Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.z, MinimapCam.position.z - MinimapSize, MinimapSize + MinimapCam.position.z)
    );
```